# Chrome/Edge and Firefox wrap long hyperlinks differently. Why?

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, cross-browser, microsoft-edge

I have noticed that Chrome/Edge and Firefox wrap long hyperlinks differently. Firefox breaks them on the slash `/` character, whereas Chrome/Edge doesn't consider the slash `/` character special.

Is there some description about this behavior? That is:

- Why is it different?
- Which one is really correct?

```css
div {
  background: silver;
  font-family: 'Courier New';
  font-size: 16px;
  max-width: 18ch; width: min-content;
}

a.bare {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>see <a href="..." class="bare">
  http://site.web/section/paaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaage.html</a></p>
</div>
```

`overflow-wrap: break-word`:

Firefox:

[image]

Chrome and Edge:

[image]

`overflow-wrap: initial /* normal */`:

Firefox:

[image]

Chrome and Edge:

[image]

Comment: They're different because they're different browsers based on different engines (Gecko and Webkit), and no particular one is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is the [line-break](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-text/#propdef-line-break) property. It specifies what characters are allowed to have line-breaks and which do not, but it's not precise. To summarize it gives some specific rules for certain characters in certain languages, but it does not specify the situation that you have asked about. It doesn't specify anything about the slash character. So since the CSS standard doesn't specify what is right, neither of these implementations are wrong.

The default value for the line-break property is auto which does the following:

> The UA determines the set of line-breaking restrictions to use, and it may vary the restrictions based on the length of the line; e.g., use a less restrictive set of line-break rules for short lines.

There is another standard, the [unicode line breaking algorithm](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr14/#SY), which is far more specific and it includes a little thing which says that slashes should provide a line breaking opportunity after them for the exact situation you have inquired about. URLs being as frequent as they are on the web, it makes sense to be able to do line breaks in them at slashes, and so it's in that standard.

According to the firefox source code as best as I could find, it says it follows that unicode standard, but that's not what it appears to be doing according to your example, instead the slash in firefox seems to provide a line breaking opportunity before it. Maybe someone with more in depth knowledge of the firefox source code could explain why it does that?

I'm not sure about the chrome line breaking algorithm because it's a lot more difficult to search the source code, but I imagine the developers decided that the '/' character doesn't deserve a line break under those circumstances based on the broad definition of 'auto' in the css spec.

Comment: Thanks, this is useful. I don't think, however, that I agree with your first statement. `line-break` seems to be intended to be used for CJK text only, so I don't think this property is really related to my example.

Answer (score -1):

`break-word`: If the exceeds the width of the line, then the word is forced to splite and wrap.

You can refer to [this doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap#values) for some explanations of the value of the `overflow-wrap` property, and I think the results shown in Edge/Chrome are correct.

In your example, the text is treated as a single word, so when setting the attribure value to `normal` or `initial`, it will not be forced to splite. You can add a few spaces to the text and you will find out this.